# AVD setting for installing firefox and chrome on Android Emulator

Tags: android, firefox, google-chrome, emulation, android-virtual-device

I want to know the settings for the AVD's if I want to install firefox and chrome on my Android Emulator.

What is the AVD setting for installing firefox and chrome. I have the following avd files chrome (com.android.chrome-2.apk) and firefox (fennec-10.0.3esr.multi.android-arm.apk)

Thanks,
parvez

Answer (score 3):

```
adb install com.android.chrome-2.apk
```

```
adb install fennec-10.0.3esr.multi.android-arm.apk
```

Run these commands from the directory  where you have downloaded the files.

Comment: Hi Kumar,I know he command to install .apk files. I want to know the settings of AVD's inorder for these browsers to be supported.

Comment: @user1271519 This page may help you with Firefox: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android/Emulator